# Creating a temporary blob for debugging purposes

Tags: oracle, plsql, blob

I am trying to debug a function I created that works with blobs, but I am getting caught up because the length of my blob is still 0.  Here is my code:

```
DECLARE 

 PUSER VARCHAR2(10);
 PDOC BLOB;
 rawbuf RAW(10);
 an_offset   INTEGER;
 an_amount   BINARY_INTEGER;

BEGIN 
 PUSER := '1234';
 rawbuf := '1234567890123456789';
 an_offset  := 1;
 an_amount  := 10;
 -- ---------------------
 -- CREATE TEMPORARY BLOB
 -- ---------------------
 DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(PDOC , true);  
 DBMS_LOB.OPEN(PDOC , DBMS_LOB.LOB_READWRITE);
 DBMS_LOB.WRITE(PDOC , an_amount, an_offset, rawbuf);
 DBMS_LOB.CLOSE (PDOC );
 DBMS_LOB.FREETEMPORARY(PDOC );

RetVal := test.my_function ( PUSER, PDOC );
COMMIT; 
END;
```

Does anyone have any insight into how to create a blob when debugging?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: FREETEMPORARY destroys that LOB. You need to call this procedure **after** the function, not before.

Comment: @kordirko sure enough, that fixed it.  Dumb mistake, but I appreciate the help.  If you create an answer, I will gladly mark it accepted